# Starting a workflow after it's been cancelled

Tags: workflow

I'm trying to fix a basic workflow that's not currently working, for some reason it's cancelling the workflow - I think it's something to do with check in / check out. I'm not too worried about this issue, I can work it out. However, what's frustrating me is during testing when a workflow has been cancelled on a document, I can't find any easy way to restart the workflow on a document.

Currently I select the document **workflow> Name of the workflow >End this workflow> OK> then navigate back to the library > select the document workflow again> Start a new workflow (name of the workflow) manually> Start.**

It's such a round about way, I expect if a workflow is 'cancelled' then the workflow should have stopped. In the same way it does when it's 'Completed'.

Is there a quicker way to do this? I'm thinking ahead as to when my clients take over the system, they may encounter the same (long winded) issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can start the workflow using code. The code has to be triggered somehow. You could use an Event Receiver for when a document is either added or updated.

If you need to be able restart a workflow by just clicking something. You could create an application page that does that. Populate a column with a hyperlink for each item.

Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nishand/archive/2008/08/27/how-to-add-remove-and-start-workflow-programmatically.aspx

```
   1: SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost");

   2: SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();

   3: SPList list = web.Lists["Shared Documents"];

   4: SPWorkflowAssociation association = AddWorkflow(); // Above function to get the SPWorlflowAssociation object

   5: SPWorkflowManager manager = site.WorkflowManager; 

   6: for (int idx = 0; idx < 10 ; idx++) // I'm assuming there would be atleast 10 items within the library

   7: {

   8: SPListItem item = list.Items[idx];

   9: manager.StartWorkflow(item,association, "you can pass any data here",true);

  10: }
```

Comment: This is really useful, we're going to be migrating thousands of documents, it'll be impossible for me to manually start all workflows that have been cancelled. We'll give this a go. Thank you.